# how do i recover information from a text file

Tags: c

I have to work with the next text File:

```
ABA     INH     1806        2   0   2
ADCA    IMM     89ii        1   1   2
        DIR     99dd        1   1   2
        EXT     B9hhll      1   2   3
        IDX     A9xb        1   1   2
        IDX1    A9xbff      1   2   3
        IDX2    A9xbeeff    1   3   4
        [D,IDX] A9xb        1   1   2
        [IDX2]  A9xbeeff    1   3   4
ADCB    IMM     C9ii        1   1   2
        DIR     D9dd        1   1   2
        EXT     F9hhll      1   2   3
        IDX     E9xb        1   1   2
        IDX1    E9xbff      1   2   3
        IDX2    E9xbeeff    1   3   4
        [D,IDX] E9xb        1   1   2
        [IDX2]  E9xbeeff    1   3   4
ADDA    IMM     8Bii        1   1   2
        DIR     9Bdd        1   1   2
        EXT     BBhhll      1   2   3
        IDX     ABxb        1   1   2
        IDX1    ABxbff      1   2   3
        IDX2    ABxbeeff    1   3   4
        [D,IDX] ABxb        1   1   2
        [IDX2]  ABxbeeff    1   3   4
ADDB    IMM     CBii        1   1   2
        DIR     DBdd        1   1   2
        EXT     FBhhll      1   2   3
        IDX     EBxb        1   1   2
        IDX1    EBxbff      1   2   3
        IDX2    EBxbeeff    1   3   4
        [D,IDX] EBxb        1   1   2
        [IDX2]  EBxbeeff    1   3   4
```

the first thing i have to do is to design an algorithm that searches a codop (ABA,ADCA,ADCB,...) for this i created a linked list which contains only the codop.

once you have found the codop on the linked list you have to print all the information that is left, for example if I have the codop ABA it has to print :

INH 1806    2   0   2

or if i have the codop ADDA it prints:

```
 ADDA   IMM     8Bii        1   1   2
        DIR     9Bdd        1   1   2
        EXT   BBhhll        1   2   3
        IDX     ABxb        1   1   2
        IDX1    ABxbff      1   2   3
        IDX2    ABxbeeff    1   3   4
        [D,IDX] ABxb        1   1   2
        [IDX2]  ABxbeeff    1   3   4
```

how do i design an algorithm that recovers all the informationof the codop after the search,(whether the codop has only one line of information or more)?? even though that information is not contained on the linked list, i created a link list because it was the way that i thought it would be more appropiate for a research algorithm

Comment: It can easily be restored from a file if you have kept reading position of the file (E.g. `ftell` or `fgetpos`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudo code:

Phase 1, build a dictionary of the input:

```
codops = {} # dictionary data type, where each entry contains an array
cur = [] # array of currently processed codop
for each line of input:
     codop = first word in positions 1-8 # adjust accordingly
     # for a new codop, add a new entry to the dictionary
     if codop != _blank_:
           cur = [] # allocate new array for this
           add cur to codops dictionary with key = codop
     append current line to cur (without positions 1-8)
```

Phase 2: Search and output

```
input = codop to search
using the codops dictionary, lookup the key=input in the codops dictionary
if the key is in codops:
      print all the lines contained in the array returned
else:
      print "not found" message
```

Is this what you were looking for?